# It doesn't take an AI to realise [api.ai] should flow into [dialogflow]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The wiki excerpt for [api.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api.ai):

> Dialogflow provides developers with the power to add conversation to devices and applications through the Dialogflow platform.

The wiki excerpt for [dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogflow):

> Dialogflow was previously named API.AI , if you want to ask any support related question use this tag instead of api.ai tag

We should merge the two tags, with dialogflow being used as it's the current name.

BTW, is "if you want to ask any support related question" appropriate?

Comment: I think it is better to make [tag:api.ai] a synonym for [tag:dialogflow]

Comment: At least the [tag:api.ai] excerpt makes sense... cannot say the same for the [tag:dialogflow]'s

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It doesn't make sense, it doesn't even mention `api.ai`.

Comment: Not sure whether to +1 or -1 for the most contrived title ever...

Comment: -1 for the terrible title. (Or it would be if I was feeling particularly cheeky. I support the proposal though.)

Comment: I think a synonym would be more appropriate here